# Detecting words through audio

Tags: c#, audio

I would like to know if its possible to capture a voice input and tell if the user said something simple like yes/no/next etc without using speech to text method. I tried googling but the results aren't favourable. Is analyzing a waveform a way to do it and how so? Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: The "easiest" way would probably be to get the user to record themselves saying the commands you want into the program; save them. Then yes, compare the waveform for similarity. Good Luck!

Comment: @C. Lang is there a code/ method that shows how to compare the waveform?

Comment: You are asking if something in computer programming is possible. The answer is always yes. Narrow down your question to not be so broad.

Comment: @gunr2171 Not always. A former coworker of mine once insisted that he had invented a mechanism that could compress literally *any* sequence of bits into something smaller. No attempt to explain [Shannon entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_entropy) would dissuade him. He insisted he could, in effect, compress the entire internet into ~1MB file. Why he's not a billionaire by now, I don't know. Since then, I've stopped saying things like 'anything is possible'.

Comment: @gunr2171 Fractal compression by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

its built in to windows, you can access it from C#

see the documentation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361683(v=office.14).aspx

and the example is pretty straightforward :-

```
// Create a new SpeechRecognitionEngine instance.
      SpeechRecognizer recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();

      // Create a simple grammar that recognizes "red", "green", or "blue".
      Choices colors = new Choices();
      colors.Add(new string[] { "red", "green", "blue" });

      // Create a GrammarBuilder object and append the Choices object.
      GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
      gb.Append(colors);

      // Create the Grammar instance and load it into the speech recognition engine.
      Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
      recognizer.LoadGrammar(g);

      // Register a handler for the SpeechRecognized event.
      recognizer.SpeechRecognized +=
        new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized);
    }

    // Create a simple handler for the SpeechRecognized event.
    void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Speech recognized: " + e.Result.Text);
    }
```